# Intel based hardware speed ups for DCT?

Tags: c, image-processing, intel, dct

We are writing an image processing algorithm targeting some Intel hardware.  Generally we prefer generic C implementations, but we have identified an algorithm that at its core does a ton of Discrete Cosine Transforms (DCT's) that works extremely well.  Unfortunately, our throughput requirements are such that a generic C implementation is about 2 orders of magnitude too slow.  I can get one order of magnitude through some other tricks, so if I can improve my DCT's by about an order of magnitude I have a path towards success.

Is the Intel MMX a way to get at hardware acceleration to do these DCT's?  Is there other intel specific libraries and/or hardware that I can exploit to speed these bad boys up?

Where do I start to look?  This is a new job for me, and my first time digging hard into Intel hardware, so any pointers would be most appreciated.

Comment: which DCT operation do you mean?  [discrete cosine transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform) or [dominated convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem)?

Comment: If your code's license is compatible with the GPL, you can look for hand-optimized DCT / inverse-DCT routines in video codecs like x264 or x265.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at Intel's [Integrated Performance Primitives](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-ipp/#support) library. It contains a wealth of routines that are optimized heavily to take use of the Intel architecture, specifically MMX and SSE. Among many other things, IPP also contains routines for the DCT ([documentation here](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/compilerpro/en-us/cpp/lin/ipp/ipps/ipps_ch7/ch7_DCT.html)).